# Is it permissible to learn out loud while the tzibbur is davening?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, torah-study, tzibur-community, priorities

In my local shul during mincha/maariv a daf yomi chabura learns out loud during davening in the same beis medrash as the rest of the tzibbur.

Do they have a right to do so? The problem is that I can't concentrate at all and my davening is ruined.

Are there any halachos regarding people learning and devening in the same room?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45957/making-very-loud-drumming-noise-during-davening Note that as currently expressed, this question is asking us to evaluate your particular situation, which we cannot do. Please consider editing this post to ask about the general issue instead (including your story as motivation if you wish).

Comment: I think there may be a difference if the room is designated as a *Bet Midrash* vs. a *Bet Keneset*. Which one is it, in your case?

Comment: @DanF, it's both, but mostly used as a Bet Keneset.

Comment: Who was there first? (Also, I think Chazal implies in several places that learning is *more* important than davening - but this does sound like more of an issue of who has the original right to be there...)

Comment: @loewian, the minyan is scheduled there every day. The daf yomi chabura recently started - but I think that's because mincha is starting later these days...

Comment: Sounds like something to take up with the Rabbi/board...

Comment: Are there 2 rooms available?

Comment: Seems that there may be a simple solution. If davening times are posted, then, technically, leraning should stop as there is a rule mentioned in Shulchan Aruch that one can't even learn during *Chazarat Hashat"z*. Additionally, the posted davening times establishes the shul's "ownership" during that time as having the right to daven. If they are just forming a minyan whenever they want and people are learning there already, then, it seems that the daveners are disturbing the learners who are already there. They should find somewhere else to daven.

Comment: This comment thread appears to be trying to pasken this particular case. I think this is a mistake.

Comment: One can learn through chazarut hashats if one doesnt belong to that minyan. Learning is not more important than davenning. If one room is only available it has to be used for davenning not learning. If one only has limited time he has to daven not learn. @DanF